# disable default validation for dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view Known as Machinefilter

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div id="filterDiv">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Filter</legend>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.Label("Machine Serial No :")
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MachineSrNo, new { @id = "SearchSerialNo" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.Label("City :")
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CityId, new SelectList(ViewBag.Cities, "CityId", "CityName"), "--Select City--", new { @id = "drpCity" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.Label("Bank Branch :")
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.BankBranchId, new SelectList(ViewBag.BankBranch, "BankBranchId", "Name"), "--Select Bank Branch--", new { @id = "drpBankBranch" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    <input type="reset" value="Clear" />
</p>
}
```

Here whenever I click on "Search" button its shows default validation. Where i have not put any validation for this view.

Answer (score 10):

ASP.NET MVC implictly does couple of validations even you don't decorate the properties with validation attributes. The couple of validations are type checking and required. These two validations will happen if you use non-nullable built-in data types like integer, datetime etc.

I hope you have properties as type integers. An integer property should have some value if you don't submit the implicit validation fails and you get an error.

**To avoid this you can use nullable types.**

For ex.

```
public class Model
{
   public int? CityId{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For MVC5, just add **data_val = false** to the helper you do not want validation on.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MachineSrNo, new { @id = "SearchSerialNo", data_val = false  })
```

Comment: Works great. Kudos

Comment: God bless you man

Answer (score -1):

check your model that you are using against this view.
you must be using Required attribute there.
remove the same from there.

Comment: Check the defaults of how a DropDownListFor works next time before you jump to conclusions.  By default, you have an int associated with the list.  The default value for the first item isn't always 0, it might be null.  In this case, the user needed to use int?.  Again, I'd read up before you assume it's user error.